# Bamboo + Stash: Please tell me who you are

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin, bamboo, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to run a maven-job with Bamboo and release a project with the maven release-plugin. However, when Bamboo tries to commit something, the following error appears:

```
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project Projectname: Unable to commit files
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] Provider message:
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] The git-commit command failed.
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] Command output:
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR]
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] *** Please tell me who you are.
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR]
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] Run
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR]
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] git config --global user.name "Your Name"
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR]
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] to set your account's default identity.
19-Nov-2013 13:20:37    [ERROR] Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

I searched the Bamboo settings and Google to find a way to set those identity-information, but I didn't find anything useful. Does anyone know, how to set those?

Comment: It's right there in the error message: run two "git config" commands. You have to run those commands as the user that executes the build, so you presumably need to do something like a "sudo so bamboo" before you begin.

Comment: So I have to log onto the bamboo-server itself and set them? I was hoping for a possibility to do that via the web-frontend. If there is no such possibility, I suppose I could do it that way. (Just wanted to say: I read those instructions, but I didn't want to have to do that on the bamboo-server itself)

Comment: I did what you said, and it worked. Thanks :) If you post your comment as an answer, I'll give you my accept.

Comment: Done. I realized that the sudo wasn't _strictly_ necessary, because you can also just edit the config file, so I've put that in the answer as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's right there in the error message: run two "git config" commands. You have to run those commands as the user that executes the build, so you presumably need to do something like a "sudo su bamboo" before you begin.

The two values will end up in the `.gitconfig` file in the home directory of your Bamboo user:

```
[user]
name = Bamboo Server
email = bamboo@yourcompany.com
```

You can also edit this file in a text editor.

Comment: I have the very same problem but the user for bamboo is properly configured. The only difference is that bamboo seems to be using the email j2ee-bamboo@mydomain whereas in the .gitconfig I have my personal email. Does git perform the matching based on the email value?

Comment: `sudo so bamboo` should be `sudo su bamboo`